# Is there a way to setup multiple users for cmder?

Tags: cmder

Does anyone know of a way to setup `cmder` so that each user has their own configuration data without having to replicate the whole `cmder` tree for each user?

It appears from my googling that the configuration gets stored in `%CMDER_ROOT%\config` except for `ConEmu.xml` which is in `%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\coneemu-maximus5`.

I would like to setup `cmder` so that the configuration is stored in `%USERPROFILE%\cmder` or something like that.